# mysql_query not sending form information to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can't seem to figure out why my form data isn't being sent to the database. I've tried multiple variations of coding and this is the only one where I could get a "result"

here's my code:

```
<?php
  #if the submit button has be selected...
  if(isset($_POST['submit_registration'])) {
  # assign variables to each form control to capture the values
    $first = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $distance = $_POST['distance'];
  # assign null to values for use with isset function to identitfy required         fields with no value
    $nofirst = null;
    $nolast = null;
    $noemail = null;
    $noaddress1 = null;
    $noaddress2 = '';
    $nocityErr = null;
    $nostate = null;
    $nozipcode = null;
    $nophone = null;
    $nodistance = null;
  # if value of variable for required field is nothing, assign something other than null to $no variable
    if($first == "") {$nofirst = '';}
    if($last == "") {$nolast = '';           if($email == "") {$noemail = '';}
    if($address1 == "") {$noaddress1 = '';}
    if($address2 == "") {$noaddress2 ='';}
    if($city == "") {$nocity = '';}
    if($state == "") {$nostate = '';}
    if($zipcode == "") {$nozipcode = '';}
    if($phone == "") {$nophone = '';}
    else {
      $insertsql = "INSERT INTO `runner`(`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `postalcode`, `phone`, `distance`)
                VALUES ('$first','$last','$email','$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$zipcode','$phone','$distance')";
          echo $insertsql;
      mysql_query($lrconnect, $insertsql) or die("Insert failed ". mysql_error($lrconnect));
        echo "connected";
      $inserted = '';
    }
}
?>
```

Here's my the error I get:

```
INSERT INTO `runner`(`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `postalcode`, `phone`, `distance`) VALUES ('Crystal','Yang','cykher@gmail.com','55555 Avenue','','Chicago','FL','39485','5555555555','5K')
```

Insert failed

Comment: What are your columns' type (and length) ?

Comment: Can you show us your Database connection code. $lrconnect

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are 
[**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** 
and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the 
future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or 
[MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: You code is suffering from the [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: distance looks fishy. 90% of what you gave is useless in debugging this. schema please

Comment: You are not closing your brace here: {$nolast = '';

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysqli_query` functions, you would put the connection first as you have.  However, you are using `mysql_query` instead which puts the query first and the connection second.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

As mentioned in the comments, though, you really should not be just inserting data that users submit through `$_POST` directly into the database.  Also mentioned in the comments, you should be using `mysqli_*` instead.  This would have made your syntax correct.

There's not a lot of work to do to convert it to `mysqli`.  Basically you just add an `i` on to the end of each place where you'd normally call `mysql`.  You'd also switch the connection and query to have the connection come first, as you have in your code.  Finally, your connection takes a 4th parameter now instead of 3, which is nice because you don't need a separate call to specify which database you want to use.

Here's an example:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USER', 'PASS', 'DATABASE');

$q_test = "SELECT id FROM table";

$r_test = mysqli_query($link, $q_test) or trigger_error("Cannot Get ID: (".mysqli_error().")", E_USER_ERROR);

while ($row_test = mysqli_fetch_array($r_test)) {

    print "ID: ".$row_test['id'];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to use connection with mysql_query function.
If you are using mysqli_query function than you must have to use connection parameter in that function.
so solution of your problem is.
 **mysql_query($insertsql) or die("Insert failed ". mysql_error($lrconnect));**